# Change relationships images Ids using JSZip

Tags: jszip

I have an "thesis" and a "model" to merge. First, what I'm trying to do is resolve the id conflicts on the Relationships. Here is my approach:

```
const modelBlob = await (await fetch(caminhoModelo)).blob();
const wordMLPackageParent = await JSZip.loadAsync(modelBlob);
const wordMLPackageOriginal = await JSZip.loadAsync(teseAsBlob);
await resolveRelationshipIdConflicts(wordMLPackageParent, wordMLPackageOriginal);
saveAs(await wordMLPackageOriginal.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }), fileName);

 async function resolveRelationshipIdConflicts(model, thesis) {
        const modelRelsXml = await model.file('word/_rels/document.xml.rels').async('string');
        const thesisRelsXml = await thesis.file('word/_rels/document.xml.rels').async('string');

        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const modelRelsDoc = parser.parseFromString(modelRelsXml, 'application/xml');
        const thesisRelsDoc = parser.parseFromString(thesisRelsXml, 'application/xml');

        const modelIds = new Set([...modelRelsDoc.querySelectorAll('Relationship')].map(rel => rel.getAttribute('Id')));
        const idMap = new Map();

        const thesisRelationships = thesisRelsDoc.querySelectorAll('Relationship');
        thesisRelationships.forEach((relElem) => {
            const oldId = relElem.getAttribute('Id');
            let newId = oldId;
            if (modelIds.has(oldId)) {
                newId = generateRandomRelId();
                relElem.setAttribute('Id', newId);
                idMap.set(oldId, newId);
            }
        });

        const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        const updatedThesisRelsXml = serializer.serializeToString(thesisRelsDoc);
        thesis.file('word/_rels/document.xml.rels', updatedThesisRelsXml);

        await updateDocumentXml(thesis, idMap);
}

async function updateDocumentXml(thesis, idMap) {
        const documentXml = await thesis.file('word/document.xml').async('string');
        let updatedXml = documentXml;

        idMap.forEach((newId, oldId) => {
            updatedXml = updatedXml.replaceAll(`rId="${oldId}"`, `rId="${newId}"`);
        });

        thesis.file('word/document.xml', updatedXml);
    }
```

After doing that, the images shows as follows:

[image]

The text inside the image reads "Unable to display image".